# Raster and Shapefiles not lining up using Geopandas, Rasterio, and Contextily

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, rasterio, epsg

I am trying to get a DEM raster to line up with a shapefile in Python, but it will not show up no matter what I do. This is for lab exercise, the entire rest of the exercise relies on these lining up, as I will be extracting data from the raster and polygon layers to a point layer.

I know how to do all this "by hand" in ArcGIS, but the point of the exercise is to use R or Python (the professor did an example with R, but we can use whichever, and I have been learning Python the past couple of months for a work project). In the class notes, he says that both files are in EPSG 3847, but the shapefile was missing the CRS, so I added the CRS to it in geopandas.

The DEM appears to be EPSG 3006 (even though it was supposed to be in 3847), so I tried converting it to EPSG 3847 and it still does not show up. So then I tried going the other way and converting the shapefile to EPSG 3006, which did not help either.

```
import contextily as cx  
import geopandas as gpd  
import rasterio  
from rasterio.plot import show  
from rasterio.crs import CRS  
from rasterio.plot import show as rioshow  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
#data files
abisveg = gpd.read_file(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Stackoverflow/Sweden/abisveg_polygon.shp')  
abisveg_3847 = abisveg.set_crs(epsg = 3847)  

abisveg_3006 = abisveg_3847.to_crs(epsg = 3006)  

src = rasterio.open(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Stackoverflow/Sweden/nh_75_6.tif')  
DEM = src.read()
```

```
### creating plot grid  
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,20), constrained_layout = True)  
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1,3)  
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])  
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1], sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)  
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2], sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)  

### Plot 1 - Basemap Only  
abisveg_3006.plot(ax = ax1, color = 'none')  
cx.add_basemap(ax1, crs = 3006)  
ax1.set_aspect('equal')  
ax1.set_title("Basemap of AOI")  


### Plot 2 - DEM  
# abisveg_3847.plot(ax = ax2, color = 'none')  
show(DEM, ax=ax2, cmap = "Greys")  
cx.add_basemap(ax2, crs = 3006)  
ax2.set_aspect('equal')  
ax2.set_title('Digitial Elevation Model of AOI')  


### Plot 3 - Vegetation Types  
abisveg_3006.plot(ax = ax3, column = "VEGKOD", cmap = "viridis")  
cx.add_basemap(ax3, crs = 3006)  
ax3.set_aspect('equal')  
ax3.set_title("Vegetation Types")
```

3 Panel map with missing DEM:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIKr8.jpg

Trying to plot the files in Matplotlib has not worked, b/c they do not align at all. I am using contextily for the basemap, and have set the basemap CRS to EPSG 3847 (or 3006, depending on which version of the GIS files I was using). The shapefile shows up in the correct location no matter the projection, but the Raster does not show up. What's weird is that if I open everything up in ArcGIS, it all lines up correctly.

If I plot just the DEM all by itself, it shows up, though I don't know where on the earth it is plotting.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10), constrained_layout = True)  
show(DEM, cmap = "Greys")
```

DEM just by itself:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQOXj.jpg

I have my code in a colab notebook here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VAZ3dgf0QS2PPBOl8KJ2FXtB2oRj0qJ8?usp=share_link

The files are here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t-xvpIcLOIR9uYXOguJ7KyKqt7wuYSNc?usp=share_link

Comment: In `show(DEM, ax=ax2, cmap = "Greys") `, you need to specify proper options to put the raster at correct place, scale and CRS.

Answer (score 0):

You could give EOmaps a try... it uses matplotlib/cartopy for plotting and handles re-projecting the data and shapes to the plot-crs

```py
from pathlib import Path
from eomaps import Maps
import geopandas as gpd

p = Path(r"path to the data folder")
# read shapefile
abisveg = gpd.read_file(p / 'abisveg_polygon.shp').set_crs(epsg = 3847)

# create a map in epsg=3006
m = Maps(crs=3006, figsize=(10, 8))
# add stamen-terrain basemap
m.add_wms.OpenStreetMap.add_layer.stamen_terrain()
# plot shapefile (zorder=2 to be on top of the DEM)
m.add_gdf(abisveg, column=abisveg.VEGKOD, cmap="viridis", ec="k", lw=0.2, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
# plot DEM
m2 = m.new_layer_from_file.GeoTIFF(p / "nh_75_6.tif", cmap="Greys", zorder=1)

m.ax.set_extent((589913.0408156103, 713614.6619114348, 7495264.310799116, 7618965.93189494),
                Maps.CRS.epsg(3006))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is most helpful!